# ReactJS :: Jest Testing :: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am currently having some trouble compiling a test for an online study task to see whether the fetch() function of my weather application is working correctly.

I have made use of the useEffect() hook to fetch the data from the OpenWeather API to store and render once the API's URL changes.

I am new to Jest testing and have tried a couple of things, following tutorials and other sources, but am unfortunately not having any success. My current solution is returning the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Please see below my code:

**App.js**

```
// Imported hooks and react libraries.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// Imported stylesheet.
import './App.css';
// Imported components.
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
// Imported countries from i18n-iso-countries to get the iso code and return the country name in English.
import countries from 'i18n-iso-countries';
// Imported icons from Font Awesome.
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faCloudSunRain,
  faHandHoldingWater,
  faHandSparkles,
  faMapMarkerAlt,
  faSearchLocation,
  faTemperatureHigh,
  faTemperatureLow,
  faWind
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

countries.registerLocale(require('i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json'));

function App() {
  // Setting the initial states of the app to store the response and the locations. Using the useState hook to set the data. Showing Durban as 
  // an example.
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
  const [getState, setGetState] = useState('Durban');
  const [state, setState] = useState('Durban');

  // Constructing the API URL and accessing the key via the process.env variable.
  const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
  const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${state}&APPID=${apiKey}`;
  console.log (process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY);

  // Using the useEffect hook to fetch the data from the API to store and render once the API's URL changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setApiData(data));
  }, [apiUrl]);

  // Constructed an input handler to get the data once requested and to store in the getState.
  const inputHandler = (event) => {
    setGetState(event.target.value);
  };

  // Constructed a submit handler to handle the request once the search button is clicked.
  const submitHandler = () => {
    setState(getState);
  };

  // Constructed a kelvin to celsius converter to output the temperature in celsius.
  const kelvinToCelsius = (k) => {
    return (k - 273.15).toFixed(2);
  };

  // Constructed a miles to kilometers converter to output the temperature in kilometers.
  const milesToKilometers = (k) => {
    return (k * 3.6).toFixed(2);
  };

  // Created a function to capitalize the first letters of each part of the countries' names.
  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  };

  // Returning the data. Included the React Bootstrap stylesheet's link and called the "Header" and "Footer" components below. I also called the
  // following from the API:

  // {apiData.weather[0].icon} - The icon displaying the current conditions.
  // {apiData.name} - The city's name.
  // {countries.getName(apiData.sys.country, 'en', { select: 'official', })} - The country's name with the first letters capitalized.
  // {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.temp_min)} - The minimum temperature.
  // {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.temp_max)} - The maximum temperature.
  // {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.feels_like)} - The "feels like" temperature, taking into account the temperatures and conditions.
  // {apiData.weather[0].main} - The summarized condition.
  // {capitalizeFirstLetter(apiData.weather[0].description)} - The full condition's description.
  // {apiData.main.humidity} - The humidity percentage.
  // {milesToKilometers(apiData.wind.speed)} - The wind speed.

  // Called the inputHandler (input section) and submitHandler (button) to get the current state's values and added Font Awesome icons. Also 
  // added a loading message for if the page load takes a while. Currently only shows if there is no input or upon refresh.
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
      <Header />

      <div className="container">
        <div className="searchsection">
          <label htmlFor="location-name">Enter Location:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="location-name"
            onChange={inputHandler}
            value={getState}
          />
          <button onClick={submitHandler}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearchLocation} /></button>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-3 mx-auto" style={{ width: '60vw' }}>
          {apiData.main ? (
            <div id="weathercontainer">
              <div id="mainweather">
                <img
                  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${apiData.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
                  alt="weather status icon"
                  className="weather-icon"
                />
                <p className="h2">{kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.temp)}&deg;C</p>
                <h3><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarkerAlt} /> {apiData.name}</h3>
                <h3>{countries.getName(apiData.sys.country, 'en', { select: 'official', })}</h3>
              </div>

              <div className="temperatureconditions">
                <div id="temperature">
                  <h5>Temperature:</h5>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTemperatureLow} /> {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.temp_min)}&deg;C</p>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTemperatureHigh} /> {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.temp_max)}&deg;C</p>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHandSparkles} /> Feels like: {kelvinToCelsius(apiData.main.feels_like)}&deg;C</p>
                </div>
                <div id="conditions">
                  <h5>Conditions:</h5>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloudSunRain} /> {apiData.weather[0].main}: {capitalizeFirstLetter(apiData.weather[0].description)}</p>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHandHoldingWater} /> Humidity: {apiData.main.humidity}%</p>
                  <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWind} /> Wind Speed: {milesToKilometers(apiData.wind.speed)} km/h</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1 id="loading">Weather Bot is Loading...</h1>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

// Exported App to Index.js.
export default App;
```

**App.Fetch.React.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';

global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        json: () =>
            Promise.resolve({
                value: "Durban"
            }),
    })
);

describe("App", () => {
    it("loads Durban city name", async () => {
        await act(async () => render(<App />));
        expect(screen.getByText("Durban")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Does anyone mind helping?

Comment: I don't see anything immediately obvious--you might want to try narrowing the sxope of the test and doing a simple test to make sure a simple function running "fetch" works. It's hard to see just the code that's failing when it's wrapped up in a lot of unrelated code and comments.

Comment: @DaveNewton I appreciate you taking a look . Thank you for your assistance. I have managed to run the test successfully.

Comment: Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to run the test successfully.

The test's code is as follows (with notes for referencing):

```
/* Storing a reference to the global.fetch function so that we can use it to cleanup the mock after we're done testing. */
const unmockedFetch = global.fetch

/* Fetching the Promise with the JSON method, which also returns the Promise with the data. */
beforeAll(() => {
    global.fetch = () =>
        Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve([]),
        })
})

/* Using the afterAll() jest hook and calling the global.fetch function to cleanup mock test. */
afterAll(() => {
    global.fetch = unmockedFetch
})

/* Adding a description of what should be executed and describing the test that will determine whether it is executed successfully or not. 
Utilizing the async function due to the await keyword being used to invoke asynchronous code. Using the expect() and toHaveProperty() functions 
to see whether the fetched data from JSON matches the keys stipulated. */
describe('Displaying the temperature and the wind speed', () => {
    test('Is it working?', async () => {
        const json = await withFetch()
        expect(json).toHaveProperty(['main', 'temp']);
        expect(json).toHaveProperty(['wind', 'speed']);
    })
})
```

I hope that all is in order and that it will help someone else in future.